# jQuery Ui Slider - How do I prevent the tooltip from showing below the slider?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider, jquery-ui-slider

With the jQuery UI Slider component, the tooltip will jump below the slider for visibility. Similar to how a dropdown will display above/below the input box when there is not enough room on the window for the dropdown options.

I need to remove that ability so the tooltip will always display above the slider regardless of screen position. I do not see an option for this in the [api documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-option), nor can I find a solution via google.

I have tried manually setting the position when the top property is calculated by the slider, but this only works part of the time and overrides the slider functionality. It is not a good solution.

```
  $slider.slider({
            range: "min",
            values: [140,0]
            min: 20,
            max: 1200,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                adjustHover(ui.handle);
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                adjustHover(ui.handle);
            }
        });

     //Tried this
     window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
        $slider.find('.slider-hover').css(top, "24.6px");
    }, false);
```

I expect that the tooltip hover will stay above the slider when the screen scrolls up or down.

**EDIT:** Another option would be a class that is added when the above/below positions change. Then I could style accordingly. But I am not sure where to add this class at.

Added a picture for clarity: [image: Tooltip below slider]

**EDIT 2:** Came up with a work around... still open to better solutions!

```
var paymentTop = parseInt($('#monthly-payment-amount').css("top"));
if (paymentTop > 70) {
    $('#monthly-payment-amount').addClass('below');
} else {
    $('#monthly-payment-amount').removeClass('below');
}
```

Test the top position, then add a class that will adjust the arrow accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `z-index` with CSS on the `.ui-slider-handle` class to force visibility

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Unfortunately, z-index is not the issue there. The slider is calculating the top value based on screen position. I would like to remove that functionality or find a work around. I provided an image for more clarity.

Comment: @Jeremy Aah sorry for the mis understanding. Waiting for your image.. ;)